# Define 2 roles for our ASP.NET Core MVC 6.0 (Admin & Users). if we do not have registration and we are authenticating users using MS Identity Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, microsoft-identity-platform

I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC 6.0 web application >> and i define it to use Microsoft Identity Platform for authentication, as follow:-

[image]

[image]

so we do not manage or register users inside back-end. now we need to define all users to have "Users" role while certain users to have "Admin" role. so how we can do so? since we are not managing our users inside SQL ? can anyone advice what are the approaches we have? now we can manage defining users with Admin roles on the back-end only (without having views to manage this).. but not sure which approach we need to follow? as we need to restrict certain actions methods and certain controllers to be accessed by users with Admin roles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using Azure Active Directory for authentication.
You can define two app roles in your app registration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps.

You can then assign those roles to users.

Comment: so i will be managing the roles and their users inside AD and not inside my application ?

Comment: also can i use `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` to mark certain action method that they can only be accessed by admin users?

Comment: can you advice more on my above 2 messages ?

Comment: Yes, the roles would be managed in Azure AD. You will be able to use the AuthorizeAttribute as long as your authentication sets up the claim type for roles correctly.